# sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server

How to create database in sql server 2005. How to start with sql server 2005.

Comment: How about reading a book? Browsing to Microsoft and read up on SQL Server 2005?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/sqlserver/

Comment: Instead of actually having to *learn* SQL Server 2005, you might want to consider outsourcing whatever problem you have to someone else.

Comment: @Ville: he outsourced it to us.

Comment: Or: http://msdn.microsoft.com/SQLServer for developers

Comment: @John: Oh I see. Outsourcing is hard. I may have underestimated the depth and scope of the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

right click on databases in object explorer. then **New Databse**. and if you are a beginer , you should learn more about databases at first. start with a book if you know about databases as marc_s noticed!

Answer (score 1):

you can make it by script or by wizard in SQL Server.

from msdn :

CREATE DATABASE database_name
[ ON
    [ < filespec > [ ,...n ] ]
    [ , < filegroup > [ ,...n ] ]
]
[ LOG ON { < filespec > [ ,...n ] } ]
[ COLLATE collation_name ]
[ FOR LOAD | FOR ATTACH ]

< filespec > ::=

[ PRIMARY ]
( [ NAME = logical_file_name , ]
    FILENAME = 'os_file_name'
    [ , SIZE = size ]
    [ , MAXSIZE = { max_size | UNLIMITED } ]
    [ , FILEGROWTH = growth_increment ] ) [ ,...n ]

< filegroup > ::=

FILEGROUP filegroup_name < filespec > [ ,...n ]